# SDL2 PointInRect If Statement not working

Tags: c++, macos, sdl-2

I'm making a little game as a small project but I can't get an if statement to do anything. If I make it !statement it works though. I run this if statement to find which cube on the "grid" (An array or cubes I render in a for loop I didn't show) the mouse clicked on. I use C++ and SDL2 on a Mac. This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

void RenderRects(SDL_Renderer *renderer);
void ToggleRect(int MouseX, int MouseY);

struct Grid
{
    bool IsActive;
    SDL_Rect Rect;

};

Grid grid[228960];

int main()
{

    bool IsRunning = true;
    bool IsRunningSim;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("My Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1000, 780, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    int h, w;
    
    SDL_MaximizeWindow(window);
    SDL_GetRendererOutputSize(renderer, &w, &h);

    
    while (IsRunning)
    {
        // std::cout << w << std::endl;
        // std::cout << h << std::endl;
        SDL_Event ev;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev))
        {
            if (ev.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                IsRunning = false;
            }
            if (ev.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                int x, y;
                SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
                ToggleRect(x, y);
            }
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        //rendering
        RenderRects(renderer);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}

void RenderRects(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1440; i += 10)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 795; j += 10)
        {
            SDL_Rect Rect = {i, j, 10, 10};
            grid[i].Rect = Rect;
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 100, 100, 100, 225);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &grid[i].Rect);
        }
    }
}

void ToggleRect(int MouseX, int MouseY)
{
    
    SDL_Point MousePos;
    MousePos.x = MouseX;
    MousePos.y = MouseY;
    for (int i = 0; i < 228961; i++)
    {
        if (SDL_PointInRect(&MousePos, &grid[i].Rect)) //This is the if that doesn't work.
        {      
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you debug this properly - in stages.  And start with a smaller set of rects than 228960 of them.  (By the way, you have an off by one error in that loop in togglerect - arrays in C++ start at index 0.)  First you have to find out what you're setting your rects too, second you have to find out what coordinates you're getting from your events, etc. etc. etc.  Debug in stages.  You can't just look at this code and say "hey this `if` doesn't work in togglerect" - you don't know that.  Multiple problems could be anywhere in this, where you have 5 loops (2 nested) and event interactions.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you again! That worked. It was setting the rect to white and then drawing over it as well as some other issues. It all works now!

Comment: This Issue is Fixed. I don't know why I can't make it say Solved so as not to waste peoples time. Its solved.

Comment: At SO/SE we don't have a "solved" state for the _question_.  What you can do, if you're interested, is add an _answer_ to your own question.  Then, you can give the answer a checkmark (the way to signal that the answer is correct).  But, to be honest, it might not be worth the effort in this case, since this isn't a general question at all that anyone else will be looking for.  These comments will _probably_ not be deleted, and that'll clue in anyone else who gets here later.

Comment: Ahh. Thank you I will do that! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this. I had to change my method of drawing since it was drawing over the rect and then showing after I changed its color. There was also an issue with generating the Rects that was probably effect it.